# "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created" only some machines. On others everything is fine

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datacontext

I have a WPF application that references DataModel project. This project references Entity Framework (EF) and has `DataContext` class defined. In `DataContext` class I have `DbSet` of entities called `Client`.

Now, in my WPF application I have a `MainViewModel` class that contains a list of clients that is populated with the clients from the database (using EF). I also have a dropdown which is bound to that list.

The problem is that on my machine, machine of two other developers and some servers everything works as it should. However, on 3 machines of some other random people (not developers) an exception is thrown: "The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created.". How could you explain that? It is exactly the same application connecting to the same database and yet such difference...Any ideas?

I am using .NET 4.5.1 and EF 6.1.1

Comment: Is your problem similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096614/ef6-code-first-model-backing-datacontext-has-changed-error-mdf-db

Comment: This can happen if they were working on a version of code which had migrations which are not in the present version of the code. I am not sure of the technical details, but EF will get confused and think the database does not match the latest version of the code. Try running `Add-Migration SyncTest`. Check what it generates. If all the statements exist in a previous migration, or in the initial schema, feel free to delete them (but leave the Up and Down methods [even empty methods]). This should fix your issue.

Comment: @Rob: they have exactly the same application as me. It works on my machine and it does not work on their machine

Comment: @TYY: not really; you linked a very basic thing. All the migrations are applied and the database is up-to-date. Everything works on my machine and few others, but it does not work on some other machines. I am stumped.

Comment: @MichalB. I understand that, but if they made any changes locally (even if they removed those changes), that would cause this problem. Ask them to run the Add-Migration command above, and see what happens. The message they're getting `The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created` is describing this situation.

Comment: @Rob: they are not developers. They do not change anything and they connect to the same database as me. They are just users of my application.

Comment: Do the non-developers have the exact same code as the developers do? Because EF will throw that error if they don't and they try connecting to the same database.

Comment: @IronMan84: I am testing the app on my machine - it works. I zip it and send it. On some machines it works, on some it throws the exception. I know it is unbelievable, but this is the way it is... I am still trying to figure it out...:S

Comment: I have a similar problem... same machine, same database, 2 different applications that use the same model (same library, same dll)... 1 application works, the otherone no... same error: `The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created`... have you solved?

Comment: To tell truth, I do not remember this app anymore. I have no idea what the problem was...